# How can i return an arraylist from AsyncTask?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I have a problem is the following: I have to take some data from mysql from android, and for that I do it with php, but since I use android 4.0 put through an `AsyncTask`. The problem is that I don't know how to return the resulting `arraylist`.

Comment: read the doc, use onPostExecute ...

Answer (score 1):

A convenient way is to make an AsyncTask an anonymous class inside your Activity class. Then in onPostExecute method you have access to all fields that belongs to your Activity + final objects from the method you create that AsyncTask in.

Comment: How can i do this?, sorry but i'm new at this